# How to pass array of user defined type to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access-2010

I have this stored procedure in SQL Server which accepts a datatable and a NewOwnerID as parameters and updates all the rows whose ID's match with the one in Datatable.

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[udpUpdateActivityLead]
@ActivityLeadTable  ActivityLeadType READONLY,
@OwnerTo            int
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE [tblActivity] 
set [tblActivity].[employeeID] = @OwnerTo
from @ActivityLeadTable
where [tblActivity].[activityID] in (Select ID from [@ActivityLeadTable])
END
```

I've used this from C# which is quiet simple. Now the worst part, I need to call this stored procedure from an MS Access front end. How do i do this?

I've tried the below in MSACCESS but get error

Created a user defined type in a module

```
Public Type MyIDs
ID As Long
End Type
```

In a form I call the updateRecord function from class clsUpdateLeads
**I get error at the fourth line of the below code**

```
Dim IDList() As MyIDs
Dim objUL As clsUpdateLeads
Set objUL = New clsUpdateLeads
Call objUL.updateRecord(IDList, Me.updateEmployeeID)
```

Definition of updateRecord function in classModule clsUpdateLeads

```
Public Sub updateRecord(activityIDs() As MyIDs, NewOwnerID As Long)
If Not (isConnectionOpen()) Then
OpenConnection
End If

Set ADOCom = New ADODB.Command
ADOCom.ActiveConnection = ADOConn
ADOCom.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
ADOCom.CommandText = "[dbo].[udpUpdateActivityLead]"

ADOCom.Parameters.Append ADOCom.CreateParameter("@ActivityLeadTable", adArray, adParamInput, 10, activityIDs())
ADOCom.Parameters.Append ADOCom.CreateParameter("@OwnerTo", adBigInt, adParamInput, 10, NewOwnerID)
ADOCom.Execute

End Sub
```

Comment: why you want to communicate from msaccess front end to sql server bac kend.instead import all data to msaccess.Do it something like this.Or first create very simple proc without table type and see if it work.

Comment: @KumarHarsh Thank you for your response but I'm trying to keep almost everything which needs brains at Server level and use the Access frontend as a mere Data Holder. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you can't pass a table type using ADODB. I think the least worst option is to create a wrapper procedure to call from Access, where you pass the integers as a comma delimited list:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.udpUpdateActivityLead_MSAccess @ActivityLeadList VARCHAR(4000), @OwnerToInt INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- VALIDATE THAT STRING ONLY CONTAINS NUMBERS AND COMMAS
    IF PATINDEX('%[^0-9,]%', @ActivityLeadList) > 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Invalid Activity Leads (non integer values found)', 16, 1);
        RETURN;
    END

    -- CONVERT LIST TO TABLE
    DECLARE @ActivityLeadTable dbo.ActivityLeadType;
    INSERT @ActivityLeadTable (ID)  
    SELECT y.i.value('.', 'int')
    FROM (SELECT CAST('<i>' + REPLACE(@ActivityLeadList, ',', '</i><i>') + '</i>' AS XML)) x(i)
        CROSS APPLY i.nodes('i') y (i);

    EXECUTE dbo.udpUpdateActivityLead @ActivityLeadTable, @OwnerToInt;
END
```

A very big caveat here, and hence the validation is that using XML to split strings will only work if you can guarantee that no special XML characters will be contained in the string.

The exact method you use to split your string parameter may vary depending on requirements and your SQL Server version. Some good reading on the subject of splitting strings can be found here:

- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [Splitting Strings : Now with less T-SQL](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Performance Surprises and Assumptions : STRING_SPLIT()](http://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/sql-server-2016/string-split)

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance.